# Change background image on menu hover in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

Here is my site ([click here](http://takeitto11.com/striper2015/boats/)) I 'm trying to get the background image to change on hover of a menu item, and I'm getting close! However, when I hover, the menu disappears and the swap back to the original image is not smooth like I'd like. Any ideas on how I can improve this??

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page - All Projects
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
/* #Start the Loop
======================================================*/
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>

<?php
/* #Get Fullscreen Background
======================================================*/
$pageimage = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_thumbnail_id',false);
$pageimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src($pageimage[0], 'full', false); 
ag_fullscreen_bg($pageimage[0]); 
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

//rollover swap images with rel
var img_src = "$pageimage";
var new_src = "";

$(".rollover").hover(function(){
  //mouseover

  img_src = $(this).attr('src'); //grab original image
  new_src = $(this).attr('rel'); //grab rollover image
  $(this).attr('src', new_src); //swap images
  $(this).attr('rel', img_src); //swap images

},
function(){
  //mouse out

  $(this).attr('src', img_src); //swap images
  $(this).attr('rel', new_src); //swap images
});
//preload images
var cache = new Array();
//cycle through all rollover elements and add rollover img src to cache array
$(".rollover").each(function(){
var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
cacheImage.src = $(this).attr('rel');
cache.push(cacheImage);
});
})(jQuery);
</script>





<div class="contentarea">


            <div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Center Consoles</a>
        <ul>
           <li class='sub'><a href='http://takeitto11.com/striper2015/portfolio/2oo-cc/'><img class="rollover" width="1500px" height="1000px" rel="http://takeitto11.com/striper2015/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Striper_HPS_1500x150010.jpg" />200 CC</a></li>
           <li class='sub'><a class="220CC" href='#'>220 CC</a></li>
           <li class='sub'><a class="2605CC" href='#'>2605 CC</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     
     <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Dual Consoles</a>
        <ul>
           <li class='sub'><a class="200DC" href='#'>200 DC</a></li>
           <li class='sub'><a class="220DC" href='#'>220 DC</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     
     <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Walk Arounds</a>
        <ul>
           <li class='sub'><a class="200WA" href='#'>200 Walk Around</a></li>
           <li class='sub'><a class="220WA" href='#'>220 Walk Around</a></li>
           <li class='sub'><a class="2601WA" href='#'>2601 Walk Around</a></li>
           <li class='sub'><a class="2901WA" href='#'>2901 Walk Around</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>

  
</div>


               <div class="clear"></div>
            </ul>
```

Thank You!!

Comment: Have you tried anything with jQuery? Essentially, you'll need to overlay the image with jQuery on `mouseenter` and switch it back on `mouseout`.

Comment: I'd love to but unfortunately I don't know enough jQuery to write it myself. Been searching for hours...

Comment: I found this, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the $pageimage into it, nor how to incorporate my links in place of $(this):   http://www.grasmash.com/article/simple-jquery-script-swapping-images-hoverrollover

Comment: You need to select the image with jQuery, then update the src of that element. `$(this)` will be the hovered link in your hover function. Run through a simple jQuery tutorial and you should be able to work this out. Have Fun.

Comment: WHY DOESN'T ANYONE EVER WANT TO HELP ME ON HERE??!!

Comment: You will get better help if you can isolate a small problem rather than asking everyone to do the entire process for you.

Comment: You are using a class named _rollover_ in your jQuery selector: `$(".rollover")`. The problem is, that you don't have such class in your html. Change those to `$(".sub")`. I don't know if that fixes the problem, but that's the first thing you would have learned if you would have done any tutorial like Derek suggested.